# return value from array index value based on input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm working on a reporting tool that I'm not sure how to build -

Basically, I am using a form, that takes the users input and converts it.

The overall structure of the object will look something like this...

```
object {
 userInput: ' ',
 available: ' ',
}
```

once the user has input some data, it should take the input and change into a different number.

```
silo_1Lookup = userInput => {
  silo_1DepthsFilling = [926, 893, 860, 827, 794, 761];
};
```

Conversion will be done in 1 function, and then updates the object.

pseudo code:

```
if (object.userInput === "0") {
  object.available = "926";
}
```

Each value will correspond with an index in that array, so if `object.userInput === '2.5'` then object.avaible will be 761 (`arrayIndex: 6`)

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this? surely an if else statement with 26 conditions isn't the way to go about this..

Comment: If else is equalling to object with 26 keys and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using a dictionary to map `userInput` to `available` value, something like:

```
const USER_MAPPING = {
  "0": "926",
  "3": "5412",
  "2": "2321"
  // ... rest values
};

// usage
return USER_MAPPING[object.userInput];
```

Such mapping is hard-coded and opens opportunities for bugs, so if there is any logic behind `userInput` and the values, you should generate some function for it:

```
return generateAvailable(object.userInput)
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for